# Multiple patterns search in a line python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to search multiple patterns in a line. In this case, I already pre-defined a pattern and compiled it as variable "p" and want to add this pattern into other array of strings that I'd like to search from line.
basically, my routine is to check if all 3 patterns can be found from line then increase a counter. but if I include pattern "p" in the search group, it will return the error
"'in ' requires string as left operand, not _sre.SRE_Pattern".
does anyone know how to also add pattern "p" in the search group in a neat way?

thanks,

```
 p = re.compile("|".join(pattern))
 for line in myfile:
      if all(x in line for x in ['DOG','CAT', p]:
           count += 1
```

Comment: The error is what is says on the box: "'in ' requires string as left operand, not _sre.SRE_Pattern". You need a string for `p`, not a regular expression. Try `p = "|".join(pattern)`.

Comment: thanks, this works now.

Comment: BTW, what if there are multiple patterns in P and if I'd like to match "All" from "DOG", "CAT", and any from P.  any way I can create in simple way without creating many if loop statement?

Comment: You should learn what a regular expression is from the documentation. Use re.find(pattern, string) with the search string.

If you compile it, then do pattern.find(string). This will only match from the start though, to search the string, use re.search.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html